# Issue with remove HTML tags in CI

Tags: html, codeigniter

```
foreach($info as $job_list){

    echo strip_tags($job_list->Job_description).'<br>';
}
```

output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </body> </html>
```

but i want to print

output :

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

Comment: Is it me or is the output is the same in both cases:! I'm getting confused here, sir!

Comment: @Russel M  Are you expecting to remove html, head, body tag?

Comment: Yes I want to remove html, head, body tag

Comment: i'm pretty sure you call a view before and after... - show your entire controller code ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($info as $job_list){

    echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($job_list->Job_description));
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer so it can be helpful to other people.